# Angular - Error: Invalid state ref ''

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
Error: Invalid state ref ''
```

I am getting this error `"Error: Invalid state ref '' <a ui-sref="{{CiSref}}">",` when i try to use the below `tag`:

```
<label><a ui-sref="{{CiSref}}">Login</a></label>
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of CiSref?

Comment: You're going to need to post more of your code. Perhaps start with the controller thats associated with this view

Answer (score 1):

Conditionally create the ui-sref attribute

`<a ng-attr-ui-sref="{{ link.Route ? link.Route : false }}">
    ...
</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Little bit shorter version:

```
<a ng-attr-ui-sref="{{ link.Route || false }}">
    ...
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same issue and realized that, it happens when the `ui-sref` is set to null

```
<a ui-sref="">Invalid</a>
```

check if the expression in not null

Answer (score 0):

the ui-sref should not be null so if you must remove all ui-sref = ""  from your html pages (views)